# Creation & pixel manipulation of 24 bit TARGA

Tags: performance, beginner, c, image

I wrote this code to get familiar with structs in C. It allows the creation and exporting of a 24 bit TGA image and changing the color of individual pixels.

My concern is the `setPixel` function, and how I could improve its performance.

First the conversion from x,y to an array index, how can I minimize/eliminate the need for this? I think I could just use a two dimensional array.

Second, is the setting of the pixel's RGB values. How could this be optimized? Would a single assignment for all three at once improve it? How would I do this?

Lastly, I was wondering if there's anyway to make `makeImage` and `saveImage` less verbose. I wasn't able to find a better solution.

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>
#include <stdint.h>

#define HEADER_BYTES 18 // Ammount of bytes header should take up

typedef struct TGAImg_t{
    uint8_t idLength;           // Length of image ID field (0-255)
    uint8_t colorMapType;       // If a color map is present (1) or not (0)
    uint8_t imageType;          // Compression and color types (0-3 and 9-11)
    uint16_t colorMapOrigin;    // Index of first color map entry
    uint16_t colorMapLength;    // Count of color map entries
    uint8_t colorMapEntrySize;  // Number of bits in each color map entry. 16 for Targa 16, 24 for Targa 24...
    uint16_t xOrigin;           // X coord of the lower left corner of the image
    uint16_t yOrigin;           // Y coord of the lower left corner of the image
    uint16_t width;             // Width of the image in pixels
    uint16_t height;            // Height of the image in pixels
    uint8_t imagePixelSize;     // Number of bits in a stored pixel index
    uint8_t imageDescriptorByte;// Document says to just keep this byte as 0
    uint8_t imageDataField[0];  // Array of image pixels.
} TGAImg;

typedef struct RGB_t{
    uint8_t red;
    uint8_t green;
    uint8_t blue;
} RGB;

TGAImg* makeImage(uint8_t idLength, uint8_t colorMapType,
                        uint8_t imageType, uint16_t colorMapOrigin,
                        uint16_t colorMapLength, uint8_t colorMapEntrySize,
                        uint16_t xOrigin, uint16_t yOrigin,
                        uint16_t width, uint16_t height,
                        uint8_t imagePixelSize, uint8_t imageDescriptorByte){
    // Allocate memory for header + image pixels (using info from header params)
    uint32_t dataFieldBytes = width * height * (imagePixelSize / 8);
    TGAImg* img = calloc(HEADER_BYTES + dataFieldBytes, 1 );
    if (!img){
        printf("ERROR: calloc fail for img @ makeImg");
        exit(EXIT_FAILURE);
    }
    // Set header values
    img->idLength = idLength;
    img->colorMapType = colorMapType;
    img->imageType = imageType;
    img->colorMapOrigin = colorMapOrigin;
    img->colorMapLength = colorMapLength;
    img->colorMapEntrySize = colorMapEntrySize;
    img->xOrigin = xOrigin;
    img->yOrigin = yOrigin;
    img->width = width;
    img->height = height;
    img->imagePixelSize = imagePixelSize;
    img->imageDescriptorByte = imageDescriptorByte;
    return img;
}

// Writes contents of a TGAImg struct to a image of name imageName
void saveImage(char imageName[], TGAImg* img){
    FILE* imageFile = fopen(imageName, "wb");

    fwrite(&img->idLength, sizeof(img->idLength), 1, imageFile);
    fwrite(&img->colorMapType, sizeof(img->colorMapType), 1, imageFile);
    fwrite(&img->imageType, sizeof(img->imageType), 1, imageFile);
    fwrite(&img->colorMapOrigin, sizeof(img->colorMapOrigin), 1, imageFile);
    fwrite(&img->colorMapLength, sizeof(img->colorMapLength), 1, imageFile);
    fwrite(&img->colorMapEntrySize, sizeof(img->colorMapEntrySize), 1, imageFile);
    fwrite(&img->xOrigin, sizeof(img->xOrigin), 1, imageFile);
    fwrite(&img->yOrigin, sizeof(img->yOrigin), 1, imageFile);
    fwrite(&img->width, sizeof(img->width), 1, imageFile);
    fwrite(&img->height, sizeof(img->height), 1, imageFile);
    fwrite(&img->imagePixelSize, sizeof(img->imagePixelSize), 1, imageFile);
    fwrite(&img->imageDescriptorByte, sizeof(img->imageDescriptorByte), 1, imageFile);
    fwrite(&img->imageDataField, img->width * img->height * (img->imagePixelSize / 8), 1, imageFile);

    fclose(imageFile);
}

void setPixel(TGAImg* img, RGB color, int x, int y){
    uint32_t index = ((y * img->width) + x) * 3; // Convert x and y to index for array
    // Apply pixel change to all colors
    img->imageDataField[index] = color.blue;
    img->imageDataField[index+1] = color.green;
    img->imageDataField[index+2] = color.red;
}
```

Comment: “I think I could just use a two dimensional array.” That would be much less efficient. I’ve written answers in this site explaining why, I suggest you search for those!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Performance

**Row vs. Pixel**

In addition to the slow `setPixel()`, offer a `setLine()` that offers reduced repeated calculations in setting many pixels of the same color.

**Block vs. Pixel**

In addition to the slow `setPixel()`, offer a `copyBlock()` that offers reduced repeated calculations in setting a rectangle of pixels.  Employ `memcpy()` when possible.

---

Portability

**File vs. Code structures**

`TGAImg` is app to contain implementation specific padding and the TARGA file have a fixed (likely no padding) definition.

This is easy to in C code if a some of extended language qualifier like `packed` is allowed.

```
// typedef struct TGAImg_t{
typedef struct packed TGAImg_t{  // example
```

If no such language extension is available, it is *work* to write portable code.  For the most part, code needs to reads the file header as an array of bytes and then form `TGAImg` one member at a time - as OP did with writing  `saveImage()`.

**Endian**

Byte order may differ form file format to code.  Various endian functions exist.

```
// fwrite(&img->colorMapOrigin, sizeof(img->colorMapOrigin), 1, imageFile);
uint16_t u16 = endian_host_to_file16(img->colorMapOrigin);
fwrite(&u16, sizeof u16, 1, imageFile);
```

**Pedantic: `int` may be 16-bit.**

Various code needs to account for that.

```
// void setPixel(TGAImg* img, RGB color, int x, int y){
void setPixel(TGAImg* img, RGB color, int_fast32_t, x, int_fast32_t y){
```

---

> Lastly, I was wondering if there's anyway to make makeImage and saveImage less verbose. I wasn't able to find a better solution.

Unclear why code does not simple use and let the caller fill in most members.

```
TGAImg *makeImage(const TGAImg *init_values)
```

**Bug?**

Trouble when `imagePixelSize` is not a multiple of 8.  Pixel depth 15 [allowed](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Truevision_TGA).

```
// uint32_t dataFieldBytes = width * height * (imagePixelSize / 8);
// Possible solution - needs review.
uint32_t dataFieldBytes = width * height * ((imagePixelSize + 7) / 8);
```

Answer (score 2):

> My concern is the `setPixel` function, and how I could improve its performance.

I don't think you can do much, there are some things but they're small. You could try flipping the definition of that `RGB` struct around (blue first) and then `memcpy`'ing the pixel, but 3 bytes is not a Nice Size (I tried this and GCC liked to implement such a 3-byte `memcpy` as 2 stores on x64, which is something, not amazing though). With the function being what it is, the arithmetic is inevitable, but you can improve it slightly (and only in some specific contexts) by using `uint32_t` for `x` and `y`, at least GCC 11.2 emitted a useless `cdqe` [*sometimes*](https://godbolt.org/z/q719MbY5q) (although I don't quite understand when or why, as it doesn't happen normally and seems entirely redundant given that `index` is `uint32_t`).

Looking at a bigger picture, a "bulk API" changes the scenario considerably (they often do, which is why they exist), a function to write/copy a contiguous region of pixels could:

- Avoid pixel-by-pixel calculations of `index`.
- Use bigger `memcpy`s to copy horizontal lines, if the source has the same format. Even rectangle-fill could use that, by filling one line first and then copying it. That's not as crazy it sounds, `memcpy` can be very efficient, it's difficult to reach that level of speed normally (you *can* though).
- Somehow (might require padding the `RGB` struct out with a dummy byte) use `memcpy` with a size of 4, hopefully resulting in an unaligned 32-bit store on platforms on which that is better than 3 individual byte stores (eg x64), while not *forcing* an unaligned store on platforms on which that is bad. Writing the extra byte "outside" the current pixel doesn't matter if you know you're going to overwrite it in the next iteration, which is something that a single-pixel API couldn't know, but a bulk API can.
- Use a fancy SIMD-shuffle based copy if the source has a contiguous format that's different from packed RGB, or even a planar format. Similarly, SIMD could be used to fill regions quickly. That's not [beginner](/questions/tagged/beginner)-friendly at all though.
- Add bounds checking (or prevent out-of-bounds access by clipping, if you prefer) at a reasonable cost, because the cost would be amortized over a bunch of pixels.

And probably more, bulk APIs create a lot of flexibility and opportunity to implement tricks and abstract them away, unlike single-action APIs. Naturally the kind of API that you want is up to you, though.

> Lastly, I was wondering if there's anyway to make `makeImage` and `saveImage` less verbose.

It's a limited-portability solution (the Portability Police may not even want me to tell you this), but if your image struct has exactly the same field order / types as the file format and it is marked `#pragma pack(1)` (not fully portable, but widely implemented) (unfortunately TGA does not have naturally aligned header fields), then you can `fwrite` the whole thing in one go. TGA has little-endian fields, which also happens to be the most popular endianness for present-day processors, so you can target a lot of hardware with that. But you *would* be targeting some set of hardware, it's not a general solution. Some RISC processors may not like accesses to the unaligned fields, but repeatedly accessing the fields is not a good thing anyway.

Answer (score 1):

Instead of hard-coding the number of bytes the 'header' of the structure should take up, you can just use `sizeof()` to get it. `sizeof()`, when applied to the structure, will return its size as if the zero-length array were not there.

Zero-length arrays are an obsolete GCC extension. Instead, you should use a flexible array member. You can do this by simply omitting the zero between the brackets.

Since you `typedef` your structures, you don't have to give them names. You can just leave them out, like this:

```
typedef struct {
    ...
} TGAImg;
```

Comment: Unfortunately due to memory alignment (I'm pretty sure that's the term), `sizeof()` returns an improper value for `TGAImg`. Since the TGA format always has a header of 18 bytes, is that considered hard coded?
Thanks for all the other advice.

Comment: I assume you mean the `sizeof` operator.  `sizeof` and `()` are separate things.  Note that `sizeof *img` will _include any padding it contains_, which is probably not appropriate for the file format.